# Why is an array with only 1 numerical item usable with some arithmetic?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't understand why an empty array, or an array with only 1 "numerical" value can be used in certain calculations.

```
[] * [] === 0 //true

[2] * [2] === 4 //true

["2"] * ["2"] === 4 //true
```

However, it does not seem that is always the case with every operator.

```
[2] + [1] === 3 // false, actual result is "21"

[2] - [1] === 1 // true
```

I also checked these, and saw expected results:

```
[4] === "4" // false
[4] === 4 // false
```

In most cases, I would expect `NaN` in any of these mathematical operations. What is it about JavaScript arrays that allows this? Is it because the array `toString` method is being used somehow internally?

Comment: binary `* - / %` and unary `+ -` attempt to convert their operands to a number. The `+` attempts `.toString()` when not given a number because it's overloaded as the string concatenation operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arrays are coerced into strings, such that `[] == ""`, `[1] == "1"`, and `[1, 2] == "1,2"`.

When you do certain mathematical operations on strings, they are coerced into `Number` types.

For example, when you do `[2] * [2]` it becomes `"2" * "2"` which becomes `2 * 2`.  You can even mix types and do `[2] * 2` or `"2" * [2]`.

When you try to use `+`, it attempts to concatenate the strings instead of coercing the strings to numbers.  That's why `"2" + "2"`, `"2" + [2]`, and  `[2] + [2]` each give you `"22"`.

Answer (score 1):

The same ol'problem of having `+` as string concatenation operator.

An array in Javascript is an Object. When you try to coerce objects into primitive values, there is an order to follow:

1. `<obj>.toString()`
2. `<obj>.toNumber()`
3. `<obj>.toBoolean()`

If you're using the `*` operator, coerce into string is not possible, so the interpreter goes to `toNumber()`.

When you're using the `+` operator, the first attempt will be `toString()`. Since `+` is also the string concat operator, then the expression will be evaluated as an array.

Yeah, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) can get ugly.

### Edit:

Some further details can be found [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/you-dont-know/9781491905159/ch04.html).

Answer (score 1):

In regards to `+`, [`+` is a coercive operator on `Strings`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1), irrespective of it being the `lvalue` and `rvalue`, I'll quote the specification here:

> If `Type(lprim`) is String or `Type(rprim`) is `String`, then Return the
>   `String` that is the result of concatenating `ToString(lprim`) followed by
>   `ToString(rprim`)

[Multiplication however doesn't follow the same rules](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5), it does however apply [`ToNumber`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3), which as you've noticed, casts a `[Number]` to -> `Number` (`+` does this as well, but it is a later step in the operator's definition)

Your last statement is answered by two rules of the `SameValue` algorithm defined in the spec, namely, if two values are of a different type, return `false`, alternatively, if two objects refer to the ptr, return true. Thus

```
a = [1];
b = [1];
a === b; // false
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do mathematical operations on the arrays JavaScript converts them to the **strings**. But **string** doesn't have multiply operator and then JavaScript converts them to the **numbers** because you try to multiply them:

```
[] * [] === 0 //  [] -> '' -> 0, result is 0 * 0 

[2] * [2] === 4 // [2] -> '2' -> 2, result is 4 * 4

["2"] * ["2"] === 4 // ["2"] -> '2' -> 2, result is 4 * 4
```

**String** has a `+` operator:

```
[2] + [1] === 3 // '2' + '1', result is "21"
```

but doesn't have a `-` operator, therefore JavaScript converts them to the **numbers** too:

```
[2] - [1] === 1 // true, because they are numbers
```

`===` it's *strict equality*, means that the objects being compared must have the same type.

```
[4] === "4" // false, you are comparing array with a string
[4] === 4 // false, you are comparing array with a number
```